# Creating a new virtualenv in Python using command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I've been trying to set up a virtual environment going by the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) and several [tutorials](http://tinwhiskers.net/setting-up-your-python-environment-with-pip-virtualenv-and-pycharm-windows/) using Python version 3.6.1 downloaded through Anaconda on Windows 10. I've set up my PATH environment variables as follows:

```
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\ 
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Scripts\
```

So far I've used the following commands...

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

**However, when I attempt to make the actual directory using:**

```
virtualenv my_venv
```

Instead of creating a directory I get the standard list of options:

```
You must provide a DEST_DIR
Usage: virtualenv.py [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity.
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE

[...]
```

I believe what I'm *supposed* to be seeing instead is something like:

```
New python executable in C:Users\...
```

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Anaconda` uses `conda` to manage virtual environments. You can simply create a new environment by `conda create -n env_name [python=x[.x]]`.

And activate a environment by `activate env_name`, deactivate a environment by `deactivate`.